# endless loop with date function

Tags: php, date, loops, for-loop

I follow a php book trying to make a calendar. Problem is that even when I follow the code to the letter I hits snags.

Here is a loop from the book

```
    for ( $i=1, $c=1, $t=date('j'), $m=date('m'), $y=date('Y');
            $c<=$this->_daysInMonth; ++$i )
```

This works in the example I download from the books site, but not in my code. I don't understand how this can lead to anything but an endless loop.

**EDIT**

Here is the whole function, now it works, but I still don't understand how...

```
    $html .= "\n\t<ul>"; // ny liste
    for ( $i=1, $c=1, $t=date('j'), $m=date('m'), $y=date('Y'); $c<=$this->_daysInMonth; ++$i) //endless loop legg til ++$c 
    {

        /*
         * Apply a "fill" class
         */
        $class = $i <= $this->_startDay ? "fill" :NULL; 

        /*
         * Add today to current date
         */
        if ( $c == $t && $m == $this->_m && $y == $this->_y )
        {
            $class = "today"; 
        }

        /*
         * Build opening and closing list for item tags
         */
        $ls = sprintf("\n\t\t<li class=\"%s\">", $class); 
        $le = "\n\t\t</li>"; 

        /*
         * add the day of the month to identify the calender box
         */
        if ( $this->_startDay < $i && $this->_daysInMonth >= $c)
        {
            $date =sprintf("\n\t\t\t<strong>%02d</strong>", $c++); 
        }
        else 
        { 
            $date="&nsbp;";
        }

        /*
         * If the current date is saturday wrap the next row
         */
        $wrap = $i != 0 && $i%7 == 0 ? "\n\t</ul>\n\t<ul>" : NULL;
        $html .= $ls . $date . $le . $wrap; 

    }
```

Comment: Is the variable `$c` incremented anywhere? And what is the value of `$this->_daysInMonth`?

Comment: It might be easier to simply increment a millisecond count and then derive that date from that

Comment: simple calendar example http://php.about.com/od/finishedphp1/ss/php_calendar.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$c gets incremented in this line:

```
$date =sprintf("\n\t\t\t<strong>%02d</strong>", $c++);
```